# Can't download driver from a usb drive

Tags: linux, driver

I am switching to linux now and I cannot get a wifi adapter to work. I dont have access to a hardline for internet access. I have downloaded the driver I need but dont know how to implement it in linux shell. it is a Realtek rtl8812au. I have the driver zip folder on a usb but don't know where to go from there. Any help is appreciated. I have only ever done stuff through sudo apt get or install.

edit: I'm running elementaryos 0.4.1 loki.

Comment: Check   https://superuser.com/questions/876727/how-to-download-deb-package-and-all-dependencies

Comment: You need to provide more information. What's inside that zip file? A .deb file? A .run file? Something else? What Linux distro are you trying? Ubuntu?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should get this package rtl8812au-dkms_4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu8_all.deb and try to install it with
 `sudo dpkg -i rtl8812au-dkms_4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg-0ubuntu8_all.deb`
Not sure that all dependencies are installed on your machine.
apt-get list below when I try to install it on live lubuntu

binutils binutils-common binutils-i686-linux-gnu build-essential dkms
  dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4 libatomic1
  libbinutils libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libfakeroot libgcc-7-dev libitm1 libmpx2
  libstdc++-7-dev libubsan0 make rtl8812au-dkms

Comment: I cannot download any drivers using the internet. The wifi for my apartment is through a different persons apartment I don't have access to. I already downloaded the right driver to a usb I just don't know how to manually download drivers like by compiling it myself in shell.

Comment: Try to download from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/cosmic/+package/rtl8812au-dkms) make sure that you choose architecture that you have on the machine. Then to pendrive and to the machine.

Comment: Damn thanks for the heads up. I would've completely screwed that up. can I just like run the .deb file and itll set itself up?

Comment: I got that file. Is there a specific location on the machine it has to be located in? I ran sudo dpkg -i /path/file.deb and got an error. it said dependency problems.

Comment: You need to follow the instructions in the error message and find according deb packages for the missing packages. Basically the dpkg is used to manage all packages installed or install new in the debian way. Dependencies gives us the possibility to use only the libraries and applications which are currently needed and which may be used by several other packages. The list of dependencies according to apt-get in the edited answer. Try search in the place which apt is searching [http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/)